# Guzzle - PHP - Several minutes timeout even when connect_timeout and timeout parameters are set

Tags: php, symfony, http, guzzle

I use the following Guzzle constructor with `connect_timeout` and `timeout` set to `6.0` seconds:

```
  $this->client = new GuzzleClient([                                                                                                                     
      'connect_timeout' => 6.0,                                                                
      'timeout' => 6.0,                                                                                          
      ... some other options ...                                                                 
  ]);
```

However, from time to time, I get the following exception when making HTTP requests:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 129810 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

The timeout is clearly higher than the timeout values I have set for the Guzzle client.

As far as I understand, the options `connect_timeout` and `timeout` should prevent such a high timeout value, is there an option I'm missing or a way to be sure the timeout will be at max 6 seconds ?

Comment: There's probably an underlying timeout occurring, but the connection was successful actually.

Comment: Maybe you want to add a `read_timeout` as well?

Comment: @CBroe I'm goint to try that, but from my understanding, the `read_timeout` option is only necessary if the Guzzle client is setup with the `stream` option (which is not the case for me). Worth to try anyway.

Comment: Hello, I work with @jean553, and adding the `read_timeout` did not help. Our last error occurrence happened "after 71046 milliseconds with 0 bytes received".

Comment: Are you by chance making Async requests?